# problema como utm_source gravity form worpress

Tags: wordpress, formularios, url

Buenas tardes tengo un problema con el plugin de gravity form y el campo de utm_source en hidden

resulta que si coloco cualquier variable en la url

https://www.enlight.mx/conoce-las-soluciones-de-energia-que-existen-para-tu-empresa/?**probando**=text

https://www.enlight.mx/conoce-las-soluciones-de-energia-que-existen-para-tu-empresa/?**utm_sourcerr**=text

https://www.enlight.mx/conoce-las-soluciones-de-energia-que-existen-para-tu-empresa/?**utm_souce**=text

la misma la detecta

pero si coloco

https://www.enlight.mx/conoce-las-soluciones-de-energia-que-existen-para-tu-empresa/?**utm_source**=probando

no Detecta el valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces no sabria que puede estar pasando e el WP o cual conflicto hay necesito asesoria en este bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro del porque pasa, pero parece que el parametro utm_source no esta permitido en la url, por ende no lo lee, posiblemente se este excluyendo, no estoy seguro de como eliminar la restriccion, pero podrias obtener ese valor con jQuery, obteniendo el parámetro que se envía por la url y asignándoselo a un input como valor, por ejemplo:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Url: example.com?utm_source=texto
    $.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        return results[1] || 0;
    }

    $.urlParam('utm_source'); // Valor Name, parametro, el mismo de la url, agrega el que desees obtener

    // Asignando el valor al input
    $('#EL ID DEL INPUT').val(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('utm_source')));

});
```

Fuentes: https://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/

Comment: Sinceramente ni idea por que esta bloqueada utm_source pero con tu respuesta solucione , me fuese gustado saber el por que esta pasando esto,  pero definitivamente me soluciono el problema. muchisimas gracias